# how to set default view for a controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have something in my controller that are shared betwin all views. So I tried to create a `_default.cshtml` and set the layout of my views with this code: `Layout = "_default.cshtml";`

and this is my `_default.cshtml`:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ahmadali shafiee";
}

@section links{
    <ul id="links">
        <li class="inner-li-en inner-li">
            <a href="~/en/about">about</a>
        </li>
        <li class="inner-li-en inner-li">
            <a href="http://2barnamenevis.com">blog</a>
        </li>
        <li class="inner-li-en inner-li">
            <a href="">projects</a>
        </li>
        <li class="inner-li-en inner-li">
            <a href="http://photo.ahmadalli.net">photoblog</a>
        </li>
        <li class="inner-li-en inner-li">
            <a href="mailto:mail@ahmadalli.net">contact</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
}

@section lang{
    <div id="lang-fa" class="lang"><a href="fa">فارسی</a></div>
}

@RenderBody()
```

and this is my view:

```
@{
    Layout = "_default.cshtml";
}

Some other content
```

but the output doesn't the result that I'm expected. It uses `_default.cshtml` as the final layout while it should use `_layout.cshtml` since I don't set the layout in `_default.cshtml`.

Comment: Layout means the master page.  Since you don't have one specified in your _default page, that is where it will stop.  See this: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/164/Nested-Layout-Pages-with-Razor

Comment: @jle If I don't set layout in my page , doesn't say the razor that "Use what it said in `_ViewStart.cshtml`"?

Comment: where is your viewstart saved?

Comment: @jle it's in Views folder. I've answered the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the logic that "If the view doesn't have a `layout` then use `_ViewStart.cshtml`" is not correct and I have to add `Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";` to my `_default.cshtml` and this fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can set it at _ViewStart.cshtml inside the Views folder of you Application, just the way you are doing in your page.

Comment: I've already have a `_ViewStart.cshtml`. So if I don't set `layout` in my view, doesn't it means that razor should use `_ViewStart.cshtml`?

Comment: @ahmadalishafiee Yes, It should work just that way. jle has writen somethign about Nested layouts that I think you should check.